# Do Java CRC32 implementations differ on 32Bit and 64Bit

Tags: java, 32bit-64bit, crc32

Is there any difference between the Java CRC32 implementations on 32Bit and 64Bit JVMs?
My problem is, that my client application (on a 32Bit platform) calculates a hash and compares it against a hash that was calculated by a 64Bit server application.
Sometimes (not always) I get different results.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: post the code for both the server and the client. the impl, itself, is different although the result is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean [CRC32](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/CRC32.html) class?

No, CRC-32 is a fixed [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_of_CRC) and both JVM version and CPU type shouldn't have any affect on it. In fact, CRC-32 is used for instance in Ethernet which is architecture agnostic.

If you know the data that manifests mismatched CRC-32, check it against some arbitrary CRC calculator, like [this](http://hash.online-convert.com/crc32-generator) one. Clearly either server- or client-side is doing the computation wrong.

My guess is that on some side not the whole stream/file is processed (few bytes at the end of file presumably).

Comment: crc32 is native, so the impl differs although the result is the same

Comment: After nights of reserach we identified the problem in our custom code.